# Can a volcano, geyser, or hot spring become treif?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, utensil

All of these things are at a constant hot temperature.

If a pig (or substance used for idolatry, like Yayin Nesech or idolatrous water) falls (or is intentionally placed) into one, can you drink or cook with the water? Are utensils made from the lava kosher?

Comment: Chamei teveria?

Comment: A pig is pretty clearly less than 1/60 of a volcano...

Comment: @DoubleAA but ain mevatlin issur levhatchilla. So the question might be better asked what about if I purposefully add a pig to a volcano for its piggy flavor goodness.

Comment: @mroll purim torah is not in season for another month+

Comment: not going to lie i thought this was a purim torah @doubleaa

Comment: Forget about the pig; how about adding a single drop of Yayin Nesech or water or lava that was used for idolatry into the volcano? There's no minimum Shiur that would make it Batel. Or what would happen if a bottle of salt water used for idolatry got dumped into the ocean? Would the entire 7 seas become forbidden? @DoubleAA

Comment: @Moshe. For that reason there are some in Israel who don't drink tap water during Pesach in case a piece of bread falls in the Kinnerret. They only drink bottled water purchased before Pesach.

Comment: I think idolotry can only taint animals and man made things, including curated Ashera trees. A sea, river, or a mountain can't become forbidden by being worshipped.

Comment: @ClintEastwood this question would be very interesting if asked simply "if there is a company that melts things, adds pig to the liquid, and then forms them into utensils, would the utensils be trief"

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the issue of shishim aside, because obviously one pig would become batul (chametz would be a different story, ע"ש), there is a fascinating Shach in Yoreh De'ah siman 94 s"k 22 (see also siman 103 s"k 18) where he explains that taste - which, for background info, normally becomes irrelevant for kashrus after 24 hours of lying dormant - which is reheated within 24 hours will have it's "pagum clock" restarted. Based on this, the taste of a pig which fell in to a volcano would never become batul as long as the heat of volcano doesn't disappear for a complete 24 hours. Although, this probably wouldn't stand, because the heat of the lava would probably incinerate the taste to the point that it loses its status of taste (see S"A O"C 442:1).

Comment: I think he's discussing taste in the walls of a vessel, not taste that is or isn't nullified in a liquid

Comment: @robev Thank you for pointing this out, I should have been clearer. The Shach there is saying that when the new heat is applied to the pot it is polet the ta'am out and then the ta'am becomes absorbed once again like any other ta'am, making the kli full of ta'am again. This happens ע"י the thing being heated in the pot. My second point was that the lava in our case might be too hot, but I'm not sure.